# Sequence diagram - python/django

Tags: python, django, sequence-diagram

If Can I use sequence diagram for represent a interaction between objects/actions of Python( with Django)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I can't quite understand your question my man.

But - the only connection between Django and any sort of diagrams would be [django-extension](http://pythonhosted.org/django-extensions/)'s functionality that allows you to get a graphical overview of your project or specific apps.

http://pythonhosted.org/django-extensions/graph_models.html

Does that help at all?

Comment: Can you tell me if this tool automatically generates UML diagrams from my project?
If yes this tool generates sequence diagram?

Comment: No, it doesn't generate an UML diagram, I'm sorry. What it does give you is more of an ER diagram, although I believe that it's missing some characteristics of a valid ER diagram (if I remember the specifications of an ER diagram correctly) - but it only displays models and relationships (without cardinality), not functions etc.